# SQL connection string from ASP.NET app does not work in WPF

Tags: sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, app-config

Several ASP.NET applications are running on the server of our company.
Connections strings in `web.config` look like this:

```
<add name="somename"
    connectionString="Data Source=SERVER\INSTANCE; Initial Catalog=DbName;User Id=user; Password=*******; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Integrated Security=true"  
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and work perfectly with no errors.

But when I copy this connection string from `web.config` to `app.config` of my WPF app, I get the following errors:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

Or (if I remove Integrated Security from string)

> Login failed for user 'username'.

Also I cannot log in via SQL Server Management Studio (causes the same errors).

My `app.config` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework"

 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                 requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="somename" 
             connectionString="Data Source=SERVER\Instance;Initial Catalog=DbName; User Id=user;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Integrated Security=true"  
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/>
    </startup>
    <entityFramework>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Both username and password are 100% correct, SQL Server uses mixed authentication.

Comment: On your working sites having "Integrated Security=true" means its using the app-pool identity to connect to SQL Server, *NOT* the username/password. And as you say you are unable to connect using SSMS with the username and password, the conclusion has to be that the username and password you are using doesn't have the required level of access to SQL Server.

Comment: Connection strings don't change from one type of application to another. The connection string is wrong for either application. You can't use both Windows authentication *and* username/password. Pick one or the other

Comment: @Dalek , thanks for quick response. But what should database admin change in order to give username and password required level to access to SQL server?

Comment: @NarminaSeyidzade the first error is clear. You tried to use Windows authentication with an account that's *not* in the same domain as the database. Don't use an account from another domain. If your machine isn't connected to the domain, connect it. If you can't, you can't use Windows authentication.

Comment: @NarminaSeyidzade your database admin will know better than me how to setup a user with access to a database.

Comment: @NarminaSeyidzade the second error says the username is invalid, period. The credentials you posted are *not* valid *SQL Login* credentials. You can't use Windows credentials in the connection string. Ask the DBA to create new ones, or reset the password of the account, if it's correct

Comment: @NarminaSeyidzade frankly though, you should ask the DBA how to connect. The fact that your machine isn't on the same domain as the server means there are more fundamental connecticity issues.Perhaps you're a conctractor trying to connect from your laptop, and hence have no credentials on the customer's network? Or the server is in a different domain, to which internal users have no access? Or perhaps you should use a *different* machine for testing?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thank you. I could connect via sa login))

Comment: That's a bad idea. `sa` can do anything in the database. A single problem and a hacker can take over the database. Or some bad input can drop tables.  If you can use the `sa` account, create a normal, restricted account and use only that.

Answer (score -1):

Managed to log in with *sa* login of SQL Server

Comment: Thats not really a solution though... you want to create a SQL User for your access.

Answer (score -3):

Edit the registry using regedit. (Start –> Run > Regedit )

Navigate to: HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA

Add a DWORD value called “DisableLoopbackCheck”

Set this value to 1

Comment: There's no need to do that at all, nor will it change anything (apart from weakening overall security). The error says *nothing* about IP connectivity, it's about permissions